# Does a redirect by Drupal's Global Redirect Module occur immediately or is there a delay?

Tags: 7, redirection

I have a website that was migrated from a WordPress blog to Drupal 7.

After running Moz Report I found lots of duplicate pages in the form of

```
/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/</body></</body></http</body</http</body>
</http</body></</body></http</body></http</body></http</body></http</body>
</http</body></http</body></http</body></http</body></http</body></html>
```

Installing and enabling the Global Redirect Module does not seem to help. 
I have enabled the default settings + add canonical link.

1. Does the redirect occur immediately or is there a delay?
2. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/

Is a path from a Wordpress installation, not Drupal.

Global redirect, being a Drupal module, not Wordpress, can only help you to set up redirects/canonicals on Drupal paths, not those from your Wordpress installation.

Presumably you'll need to add redirect/canonical functionality to your Wordpress installation to continue.

Comment: I've seen the same paths come from Drupal after WP->D7 migration. So there is *slight* chance her question is legit here. Not enough data to tell now.